# Close ServerSocket in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have the following program:

```
package testServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*; 

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket (8073);
         socket.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see i close my socket at the end of the program. However when i relunch my program i get 
Exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:414)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:326)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:192)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:104)
    at testServer.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:10)
```

why it is happening ? i thought  that after calling the `close()` the port can be reused.
I checked by `netstat`that this socket is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Are you sure that this port isn't in use somewhere else?  Are you sure that the program is closed before you try running it again?

Comment: @Makoto Yes i checked it by netstat

Comment: The socket keep binded forever ? or if you wait for certain time the port is released? Maybe is something related to the OS.

Comment: @molokoV Socket i lost forever

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work (at least it works for me).

I guess you have a suspended debugging session of your code somewhere in your IDE.

- If you are on Linux, type the following to know who uses the socket:
  `netstat -t -l -p | grep 8073`
  (if it is not you, use sudo...)
- On Windows, I recommend using TCPView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437)

Answer (score 0):

You may have ran this program before and didn't close the socket properly for some reason, so it can still be opened (or another blocking network state), not letting you listen on it again.

Since you are running on Windows, you can check what's using this port (and kill that bastard if it's the case) with [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals//bb897437.aspx).